# Why is the CouchDB JWT Authentication with Auth0 not working for me?

Tags: jwt, couchdb, auth0

I have been trying to use the JWT authentication method in CouchDB together with Auth0. Following the Documentation at https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/server/authn.html#jwt-authentication , i added the authentication_handlers in my default.ini file and configured jwt_auth and jwt_keys like this:

```
[jwt_auth]
; List of claims to validate
required_claims = alg,kid,sub

[jwt_keys]
rsa:<kid> = -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n
<PublicKey>
\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n
```

I got the kid and the public key from Auth0 (https://[myDomain]/.well-known/jwks.json). Now when i request the JWT Token and add it to the CouchDB request against the _session endpoint i get the following response:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "userCtx": {
        "name": null,
        "roles": []
    },
    "info": {
        "authentication_handlers": [
            "cookie",
            "default"
        ]
    }
}
```

I feel like i am doing something wrong within the default.ini file. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is pretty embarrassing but my problem was that I didn't enter the public key in PEM format, so all i had to do was to use this command:

`curl https://[myDomain]/pem -s | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout`

to get the PEM format and use it to configure the CouchDB.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't enabled JWT authentication in CouchDB. I say this because this:

```
    "info": {
        "authentication_handlers": [
            "cookie",
            "default"
        ]
    }
```

should also include `"jwt"`.

To get that, the `[chttpd]` block in CouchDB config should include:

```
{chttpd_auth, jwt_authentication_handler}
```

In addition, I don't think you need to have those three required claims listed. I got this working just the other day, and as those are required by Couch, you don't need to list them. Indeed, when I listed any one of them I got an error about "duplicate requirement" or something.

Also, make sure there's no `iss` (issuer) claim in the JWT. This is an issue likely to be fixed in a future release, but as of the time of writing, to get this to work with Couch 3.1 I had to explicitly make sure there was no `iss` claim.

More details [in this issue](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/pull/2946).