# CouchDB JWT Authentication with asymmetric keys

Tags: jwt, couchdb

Id like to use JWT Auth with CouchDB as described here
https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.2-docs/api/server/authn.html?highlight=jwt#jwt-authentication

This Stackoverflow question also helped a lot:
[Why is the CouchDB JWT Authentication with Auth0 not working for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63674786/why-is-the-couchdb-jwt-authentication-with-auth0-not-working-for-me)

What I have so far is the following configuration:

```
[chttpd]
authentication_handlers = {chttpd_auth, jwt_authentication_handler}, {chttpd_auth, cookie_authentication_handler}, {chttpd_auth, default_authentication_handler}


[jwt_auth]
required_claims = exp

[log]
level = debug

[jwt_keys]
rsa:fqT4qxoKNIwJSUSdhEL3KYRjl2tsz-tRMcZr_V16skM = -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAooP42fI/5PcuI5AflBpn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\nPUyoxOpC0reaacfiKOqaabkCAwEAAQ==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n
```

And I see *JWT* as a valid option if I query _session

```
 curl 127.0.0.1:5984/_session
{"ok":true,"userCtx":{"name":null,"roles":[]},"info":{"authentication_handlers":["jwt","cookie","default"]}}
```

But my request with a Bearer Token fails:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer $REALLY_LONG_STRING' 127.0.0.1:5984/

{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Not a valid key"}
```

I think CouchDB cannot parse the PEM string, looks like Im landing here: https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/main/src/jwtf/src/jwtf_keystore.erl#L142

That is as much Erlang as I can do, so Im lost now.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe I missed a \n O_o
Works now as advertised

```
[jwt_keys]
rsa:fqT4qxoKNIwJSUSdhEL3KYRjl2tsz-tRMcZr_V16skM = -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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\nPUyoxOpC0reaacfiKOqaabkCAwEAAQ==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n
``
```